EMC considerations when driving stepper motors through cable
I am developing a driving circuit for a pump — essentially a stepper motor. The PWM output signals that drive the windings are connected through a connector on the PCB and an approximately 50cm cable containing the four phases. The motor operates at 5V and at a relatively low frequency, around 1kHz. The entire system is enclosed within a grounded metal box. I am aware of some guidelines regarding the layout of the board, such as the Texas Instruments report on "Best Practices for Board Layout of Motor Drivers".
My concern is how much I should worry about the length of the cables. Of course, the added length will increase inductance and introduce extra losses. Will this affect the motor's performance? Will the back-EMF be worse since it travels back through the 50cm cable? Do I need to worry about EMC?
What are the factors that one should consider when designing such a system (board and harness)?

At such low frequencies, cable lengths won't matter that much. The main concern is probably voltage drop more than anything else. How much current does it draw and how thick are the cables?

@Lundin the motor draws about 0.45-0.5A. I have not yet decided on a specific awg for the cables

Ok well if you can conclude a minimum voltage for the motor, you can calculate how much voltage drop that's allowed and then pick length & AWG accordingly, then take it from there. EMI counter-measures would mainly be about slope control of the PWM as well as putting freewheel diodes as close to the motor as possible.

Are you selling this as a product, and/or will it be working around other electronic equipment?

@Lundin unfortunately the freewheel diodes cannot be mounted mounted near the motor but on the PCB, meaning next to the connector best case. Do you think EMI can decrease motor performance or reliability?

@imnotarobot the setup is used for performing an experiment; it will be around other electronics equipment such as camera, leds but the mounting distances are not very tight

@geo66 It's not an issue for the motor but for the driver circuitry and also other nearby electronics. The closer to the EMF source that you catch the spikes, the better. For solenoids etc there's sometimes freewheel diodes molded into the cable/connector assembly. But placing them on a PCB is probably the most common solution.
